# List children of second level sub page

Tags: menus, pages, sidebar

Top Level Page
- Second Level Page
   --- Child Page
   --- Child Page
   --- Child Page

The goal here is to list all children of second level, I have that done from the codex. However, when I click on a Child, the children should still display because we're technically still inside of the Second Level.

```
<?php
// Globalize the $post variable;
// probably already available in this context, but just in case...
global $post;
    wp_list_pages( array(
        // Only pages that are children of the current page
        'child_of' => $post->ID,
        // Only show one level of hierarchy
        'depth' => 1
    ) );
?>
```

Comment: Do you always want to show all children to the top level page, even grandchildren? OR do you only want to show the grandchildren when you're view the second level page?

Comment: I only want to show the grandchildren when im viewing the second level page..

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after?

```
<?php
    if($post->post_parent) {
        // if $post has parent than it is "Second level" and show its children.
        $children = wp_list_pages("child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
    } else {
        // else it's a "Top level" so display children & grand children? 
        $children = wp_list_pages("child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
    }

    if ($children) {
        echo "<ul>$children</ul>";
    }
```

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#List_subpages_even_if_on_a_subpage